# How to properly set a default value to a class property IF the user has not passed it to the constructor himself?

Tags: javascript

I've a class called Server which is used to create server instances. One of the properties of this class is called rooms and since I want all servers to have the same default rooms when they're first initialized, I'd like to set a default value but I also want to be able to create instances with rooms different than the default ones for when I'm creating the instances using database records which may have more than the default rooms.

My class looks like this right now

```
module.exports = class Server {
    constructor(name, image, rooms) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.endpoint = '/' + name;
        this.rooms = rooms
    }

    save(){
        return database.execute(
            'INSERT INTO servers (name, image, endpoint, rooms) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
            [this.name, this.image, this.endpoint, this.rooms]
        )
    }
}
```

so right now I could do this to set the default rooms when I'm creating a server and saving it to the database like this:

```
router.post('/createServer', function(req, res, next) {
    let server = req.body;
    let defaultRooms = [
        {
            name: 'General', history: []
        }
    ]
    let socketServer = new Server(server.name, server.image, defaultRooms);
    socketServer.save();
    socketServer.createSocketIoNamespace();
    res.send(socketServer);
});
```

This should work but I was wondering if I could somehow implement this straight to the class. For example, if I instantiate a server like this:

```
new Server(name, image)
```

The instance would use the default rooms, however, if I instantiate it like this:

```
new Server(name, image, rooms)
```

The instance would have the passed rooms

Comment: Setting a default value to a function is clearly defined here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a default value in the constructor of the class:

```
module.exports = class Server {
  constructor(name, image, rooms = [{name: 'General', history: []}]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.endpoint = '/' + name;
    this.rooms = rooms
  }

  save(){
    return database.execute(
        'INSERT INTO servers (name, image, endpoint, rooms) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
        [this.name, this.image, this.endpoint, this.rooms]
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks good but if I were to have 2-3 default rooms, the constructor is gonna look messy, wouldn't it?

Comment: In this case, you can store default rooms in constant, import and pass to the constructor as default value like `rooms = DEFAULT_ROOMS`